# Using CSS to create three icons on a row

Tags: html, css

I have three icons which need to be placed on one row. How do I achieve this using CSS?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
```

And what follows is the CSS I already have:

```
.icon {
    min-height: 20px;
    max-width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.icon:nth-child(3n+0) {
    clear:right;
    display:block;
}
```

The above code results in two icons on one line, then one icon on the next line followed by two icons on the next etc.

What I'm hoping for is, three icons on each line.

Comment: Do the icons need to be in `<div>` tags?

Comment: Please see my answer. Here is the live preview http://jsfiddle.net/J4z7p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your icons in an element with a max-width less than 4x the width of your icon element (to deal with box model differences between browsers) that will take care of things.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMcht/1/).

```
.icon{max-width:70px;}
.icon span {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.icon span:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color:blue; /*just to highlight it*/
}

<div class='icon'>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Everybody - Thanks for the feedback, it has been very helpful! We found the above solution closest to what we required.

Answer (score 2):

why not use `float: left` with fixed `width` on parent element? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbrh/)

Answer (score 2):

This is working >> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4z7p/)

```
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>


.icon {
    min-height: 20px;
    max-width: 20px;
    min-width: 20px;
    display:inline;
    background-color: red;
    border-style:dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
    float:left;
}
.icon:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `3n+1`. In CSS, element indexes are 1-based.

Side-note: What's the deal with `min-width:20px; max-width:20px`? Why not just put `width:20px`?